# How to get the sum of two object keys that meet a condition

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have one obj which has the following key/values

```
var pay = [
  {
    journal: 23,
    regdate: "31/08/2021",
    account: "2.1.01.0001.02181 Folha de Pagamento:Salarios a Pagar",
    debitvalue: "3003,58",
    creditvalue: "",
    itemdescrip: "Valor ref folha de pgto, mês 08/2021",
    name: "",
    branch: "",
    costcenter: "",
    message: "",
  },
  {
    journal: 23,
    regdate: "31/08/2021",
    account: "2.1.01.0001.02181 Folha de Pagamento:Salarios a Pagar",
    debitvalue: "",
    creditvalue: "4003,58",
    itemdescrip: "Valor ref folha de pgto, mês 08/2021",
    name: "",
    branch: "",
    costcenter: "",
    message: "",
  },
];
```

I would like to subtract all the "debitvalue" from "creditvalue" where a condition is met, i.e. account key contains 2.1.01.0001.02181

I've tried map, filter, indexOf, contains and all of which returns [].

Expected result should be 3.000
I'm beginning with javascript and I don't know too much. Thanks.

Comment: what should be your expected result. Please add that also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```
let diff

pay.forEach((obj) => {
  if (obj.account.includes('2.1.01.0001.02181')) {
    let credit = parseInt(obj['creditvalue'].replace(/,/g, '.')) || 0
    let debit = parseInt(obj['debitvalue'].replace(/,/g, '.')) || 0

    diff = credit - debit
  }
})

console.log(diff)
```

I threw in some regex to deal with the commas in your data.

Comment: Thanks for that! What does the | | 0 do?

Comment: You're welcome! `|| 0` means "or zero" and if `parseInt()` fails (like where your value in your data is `""`) it'll convert `NaN` (JS for Not a Number) to zero.

Comment: Thanks for that! With your RegExp solution and the first answer, I was able to get it to work! I don't know why but your code above with the updated values returns 4,003.58

Comment: I didn't know I could use condition when declaring it, thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with simple array functions as .reduce

```js
var pay = [
  {
    journal: 23,
    regdate: "31/08/2021",
    account: "4.1.01.0001.04200 Despesas com folha de pagamento:Salarios",
    debitvalue: "4003.58",
    creditvalue: "",
    itemdescrip: "Valor ref folha de pgto, mês 08/2021",
    name: "",
    branch: "",
    costcenter: "",
    message: "",
  },
  {
    journal: 23,
    regdate: "31/08/2021",
    account: "2.1.01.0001.02181 Folha de Pagamento:Salarios a Pagar",
    debitvalue: "",
    creditvalue: "4003.58",
    itemdescrip: "Valor ref folha de pgto, mês 08/2021",
    name: "",
    branch: "",
    costcenter: "",
    message: "",
  },
];

const totalAmount = pay.reduce( (total, currentPay) => {
    
    if (currentPay.account.includes("2.1.01.0001.02181")) {
        total = total + +currentPay.creditvalue - currentPay.debitvalue;
    }
    return total;
  }, 0)

console.log(totalAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks! Considering your function and the parse float below, how should I implement this in one line if possible. This total = total + +parseFloat(currentPay.creditvalue.replace(/,/g, '.')) - parseFloat(currentPay.debitvalue.replace(/,/g, '.')); returns NaN

Comment: What you are doing is correct, but you need to check that debitvalue and creditvalue are !== ''" because parseFloat("") is NaN, so you'll have to add validation.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve my needs I used the collaboration of the lads to implement the following code

```
const totalAmount = pay.reduce( (total, currentPay) => {
    
      if (currentPay.account.includes('2.1.01.0001.02181')) {
          var d = parseFloat(currentPay.debitvalue.replace(/,/g, '.')) || 0;
          var c = parseFloat(currentPay.creditvalue.replace(/,/g, '.')) || 0;

          total += +c - d;
      }
      return total;
      }, 0)
```

Thanks guys!